# extracting taskwarrior filter in bash function

Tags: bash, taskwarrior

I try to add an alias to annotate a task (taskwarrior):

```
function ta() {
  task $1 annotate ${@:2}
}
```

could be a good alias but $1 can't be a multiple filter words. Is there a way to recover the entire taskwarrior filter?

`ta +bob "annotation"` will works, `ta +bob project:alice "annotation"` will not. Of course I can type `ta "+bob project:alice" "annotation"` but this is not wonderfull…

Comment: your question is not clear: what is a "filter"? how do you decide which words are part of the filter and which must go at the end of the command line?

Comment: all words before the taskwarrior <command> : active, all, blocked, blocking, burndown.daily, burndown.monthly, completed, count, export, ghistory.annual, history.annual, ids, uuids, information, list, long, minimal,… and all User Defined Attributes

Comment: `task _commands` returns all taskwarrior commands

Comment: but you have no _command_ in your function call. where is the filter in `ta a b c d a 1 project:a b rv`?

Answer (score 1):

Impossible. Taskwarrior filters have specific format (+tag, proj:text,…) but can also have search filter without any specific format.